# How do I optimize my code with try statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a problem that it takes a long time to execute the code that follows the try. It can be up to 10 seconds. Can you think of any optimization?

```
  try:
        error_message = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=0).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span[2]")))
        assert error_message.text == "Invalid username or password."
        print("3")
        print("Invalid username or password.")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()

    except TimeoutException:
        print(time.time(), "3")
```

Comment: You explicitly ask your code to wait (`WebDriverWait`) until a certain element is visible. What exactly do you want to optimize?

Comment: If you're asking "How do I make my code generate a TimeoutException more quickly?", try specifying a small nonzero value for the `timeout` argument. If you're asking "how do I make the web driver load the page more quickly so it doesn't timeout as often?", I'm not optimistic that there is a way. Most likely the developers of the web driver have already made it as fast as they could.

Comment: Yes, I want TimeoutException more quickly, but if I use timeout=1 . The result is the same.

Comment: Can you post the code that initializes the web driver? Are you using implicit waits?

Comment: Maybe my problem is in definition of `error_message = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=0).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span[2]")))` Maybe I would use other code for search more quickly...

Answer (score 1):

I put the part of code for initializing the web drive. Maybe here is something wrong what do it wait in try long time.

```
    def setUp(self):
    p_test = Logintest()
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("https://localhost/spcssd")
    print("TC_S_F.IA.AD001_tEST")
    delay = 20  # seconds
    # assert "Log in to spcssd" in self.driver.title
    try:
        element_present = WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "kc-info")))
        print("Page is ready!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time!")
```